# MySQL insert multiple rows and don't update existed rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table just like the following one.
It's a price talbe name `price_data` and it contains a unique key `DateTime` and a value `price`.

```
 +----------+-------+
 | DateTime | price |
 +----------+-------+
 |2018-01-01| 100.2 | 
 |2018-01-02| 101.5 | 
 +----------+-------+
```

I want to insert multiple price data into the table simultaneously.
Thus, I can use the following SQL to accomplish that.

Insert two rows just for example.

```
INSERT INTO `price_data` (`DateTime`, `price`) VALUES
('2018-01-03', 100.0),
('2018-01-04', 101.2);
```

P.S. In the real case, I will insert over 100 rows simultaneously.

The above SQL is total OK for the task.

However, if the data that will be inserted had been in the table. For example: `('2018-01-02', 101.5)`. There is an error since the key had existed.

I find the two ways to solve the problems.

1. `INSERT IGNORE`
2. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

In the first case, it works and doesn't print any error message. However, according to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548570/8510170), `INSERT IGNORE`will hide all errors rather than the only key duplicated.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `price_data` (`DateTime`, `price`) VALUES
('2018-01-02', 101.5),
('2018-01-03', 100.0);
```

In the second case, it works and doesn't print any error message too.
However, there is a side effect that the SQL will update at least one column. Because I don't want to update any column if the row existed, I will let the key `DateTime` be updated to the new `DateTime`. Since the `DateTime` will equal the new `DateTime`, there isn't any change in the table.

```
INSERT INTO `price_data` (`DateTime`, `price`) VALUES
('2018-01-02', 101.5),
('2018-01-03', 100.0);
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DateTime=VALUES(DateTime);
```

Is the second way better?

Are there other ways to accomplish that and waste less time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should be fine. Only side effect is that if you have an Auto-increment column in your table; it will also get unnecessarily incremented; however it will not be used in current query.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the problem is in using the first way? If you don't want to update existing columns, it looks pretty good to me

Comment: One option: Unique key on both columns, and insert one record at a time.

Comment: @NicoHaase according to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570) There are three problems.
1. Inserting a duplicate key in columns with PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.
2. Inserting a NULL into a column with a NOT NULL constraint.
3. Inserting a row to a partitioned table, but the values you insert don't map to a partition.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because I have lots of rows needed to be inserted, inserting one record at a time will be too slow. Thus, I want to use the batch insert.